# Is it possible to program a Wireless Access Point?

Tags: wireless

I need to modify the way the wireless access point handle its authentication method.
Is it possible to change the behaviour of wireless access point a little bit?
If so, by using what library? On what operating system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on various things, the first being whether your router can utilize custom firmware.
Some routers like the Linksys WRT54G (pre V4 or the GL version) use a Linux based firmware that allow you to do alot more with the routers hardware. 
There are some custom distributions for these devices like [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/), however [OpenWRT](http://openwrt.org/) might be the best place to start if you're comfortable with Linux.

I would start by looking if your router is listed as being supported on the above sites

Unfortuanetly there isn't one specific library that I know of that will help you here, you might have to reimplement part of the security logic in these small distros and recompile them to achieve what you want

Comment: So can I say that if it is possible to use DD-WRT or OpenWRT to the access point, every part of the access point is programmable?

Comment: Sure, if you willing to reprogram some lower level stuff on the router

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the default firmware on your access point?  If so, you may find that there are many more configuration options availible, including more authentication options on third-party (free) software such as Tomato and DD-WRT.

Comment: Hi george, can you tell me more on this?
Currently I don't have an access point with me.
I need to do a research first if it is possible to modify the way a wireless access point work.

What can software like Tomato and DD-WRT do? Is it possible to access the whole source code of the access point?
For example, is it possible to make it such that everytime a user enters the wireless network, I do something like sending a TCP/UDP message from the wireless access point to another computer?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure.  I've used DD-WRT out of the box, not with adding additional programmed functionality.  However, I'm pretty sure it's open source, so you may be in luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a quick start, this may solve your problem:

[Chillispot](http://www.chillispot.info/)